# Ionic 2 Geofence plugin not working in iOS

Tags: ionic2, ionic-native

Ionic 2 Geofence plugin not working in iOS, though device log showing fence is registered and start tracking but transition not triggering on device,

pls help

Answer (score 0):

> This is a known issue of the [cordova-plugin-geofence](https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence)

*Apple won't let you deploy an app that is constantly looking for location, that would be a drain on resources.*

The issue is when the app is minimized, IOS in an attempt to reduce load kills the Webview, once the app is opened again it takes a moment with the correct plugin to recover but by that time, the code fails to execute the transition.

a possible solution is to add parameters in the URL as a query string so that once the app does recover it can just grab the parameters and execute the trigger event.

This should resolve the issue. without to much of a major change even just an add-on function.

[FYR](https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence/issues/193)

Comment: Thanks Anoop.
please let me know where I can put URL as a query string, I am not getting exactly what has to do.